# Use Greasemonkey to modify Google Instant results?

Tags: javascript, search, autocomplete, greasemonkey

I'm trying to write a script for Greasemonkey to modify Google Instant results. I have no problem modifying results for NORMAL Google search when it isn't Instant, but when it IS instant, it's difficult because the results are always changing. My problem is that I don't know how to write the code to catch every time the page changes and then modify it—in a sensible manner.

My best option so far is to catch keyup events then modify the page after each event, but I would imagine that is a bit too strenuous. Is there a more efficient way of doing things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the most robust/simple way is to use the `waitForKeyElements()` function like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6935428/why-doesnt-this-userscript-work-on-facebook/6935777#6935777), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539088/works-as-javascript-but-doesnt-work-as-a-greasemonkey-script/7542679#7542679), or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018543/get-contents-of-an-iframe-which-has-ajax-content-with-greasemonkey/7020269#7020269).

Note that this function requires jQuery in your script -- which is a good idea anyway. To do that add this line to the [Metadata Block](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block) of your script:

```
// @require http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js
```

---

Other methods include: listening for `DOMSubtreeModified` or intercepting AJAX calls.  These would work but are overly complicated, in practice, especially on ever-changing Google pages.